# why does this query not give me only the specified accounts?

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle SQL Developer
I expect to see:

In the subquery, I have that the rownumber be less than 2. When I run this query separately, it gives me 2 accounts. However, when I'm running the entire query, the list of account numbers just goes on! what's happening here?

```
SELECT m.acctno, i.intervalstartdate, d.name, i.intervalvalue
FROM endpoints E
JOIN meters m on m.acctid = e.acctid
LEFT JOIN intervaldata I ON I.acctid = M.acctid
LEFT JOIN endpointmodels EM ON EM.endpointmodelid=E.hwmodelid
LEFT JOIN datadefinitions D ON D.datadefinitionid = I.datadefinitionid
WHERE 1=1
AND E.statuscodeid = 8
AND m.FORM = 2
and exists
( 
   SELECT m2.acctno
    from acct m2
    where m2.acctno is not null
    --and m2.acctno=m2.acctno
    and rownum <= 2

 )
AND D.datadefinitionid =7077
AND I.intervalstartdate BETWEEN '24-SEP-2017 00:00' and '25-SEP-2017 00:00' 
--TRUNC(sysdate - 1) + interval '1' hour AND TRUNC(sysdate - 1) + interval 
'24' hour
ORDER BY M.acctno, I.intervalstartdate, I.datadefinitionid
```

This query is supposed to give me 97 rows for each account. The data i'm reading, the interval values, are the data we report for each customer in 96 intervals. so Im expecting for 2 accounts for example, to get 194 rows. i want to test for 2 accounts now, but then i want to run for 50,000. so with 2, it's not even working. Just giving me millions of rows for two accounts. Basicaly, i think my row num line of code is being ignored. I can't use an in clause because i cant pass 50,000 accounts into there. so I used the exist operator.
Let me know!

Comment: Is this on Oracle? Can you provide sample data for each table, and provide the output you expect to have for it?

Comment: yes it is, I cannot give sample data on because its private information ( account numbers) . However, if you look in the select statement, i expect to see the type of itnerval data, acctnumber, and the interval value. Does this help?

Comment: Sample data does not have to be real data.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is in trying to use `and exists (...)` clause. The `exists` predicate returns true if the subquery returns any rows at all. So, in your case, the result of `exists` will always be true, unless the table is empty. This means it has no effect whatsoever on the outer query. You need to use something like

```
inner join (SELECT m2.acctno
from acct m2
where m2.acctno is not null
--and m2.acctno=m2.acctno
and rownum <= 2) sub1 
on sub1.acctno = m.acctno
```

to get what you want instead of `and exists (...)`.

Comment: hey, so I did this, i added the inner join but the thing is , i want to know how to add the "on" portion of the inner join i was thinking of stealing                                
    join acct m on m.acctid=e.acctid from the beginning into the on portion. What do you think?

Comment: yes, I have edited my answer to include the `on` clause. Does it work?

Comment: It keeps saying missing keywords at the part where i write `sub1 m on m.acctid=e.acctid ` after the join

Comment: What exactly is sub1?

Comment: `sub1` is an alias for the subquery, similarly to how `m` is an alias for `meters` table. No need to write `sub1 m on m.acctid=e.acctid`. Should be `on sub1.acctno = m.acctno`

Answer (score 0):

One obvious mistake is the date condition, where you require a date to be between two STRINGS. If you keep dates in string format, you will run into thousands of problems and bugs and you won't be able to fix them.

Do you understand that '25-APR-2008 00:00:00' is between '24-SEP-2017 00:00:00' and '25-SEP-2017 00:00:00', if you compare them **alphabetically** (as strings)?

The solution is to make sure the date column is in DATE (or TIMESTAMP) data type, and then to compare to dates, not to strings.

As an aside - this will not cause any errors, but it is still bad code - in the EXISTS condition you have a condition for ROWNUM <= 2.  What do you think that will do? The subquery either returns at least one row (the first one will automatically have ROWNUM = 1) or it doesn't. The condition on ROWNUM in that subquery in the EXISTS condition is just garbage.